# How to run a funtion that accepts user input over a range in python

Tags: python

I'm new on stackoverflow and relatively new to python.

I'm trying to create a payoff diagram for three different put options, and then combine the three results to create a risk profile (this assumes that each option is held in a portfolio)

I would like to set this up so that the code accepts user input for for the strike, premium, and position arguments and displays the results over the market range.

This is along the lines of what I would like to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def put(futures, strike, premium, position):
    if position > 1:
        if futures > strike:
            pos_value = -premium
        else:
            pos_value = (strike - futures - premium)
    else:
        if futures < strike:
            pos_value = futures - strike + premium
        else:
            pos_value = premium
    return pos_value

market_range = range(300, 925, 25)

put1 = [put(i, int(input("Put1 strike: ")), int(input("Put1 premium: ")), int(input("Put1 position: "))) for i in market_range]
put2 = [put(i, int(input("Put2 strike: ")), int(input("Put2 premium: ")), int(input("Put2 position: "))) for i in market_range]
put3 = [put(i, int(input("Put3 strike: ")), int(input("Put3 premium: ")), int(input("Put3 position: "))) for i in market_range]

riskprofile = list(map(sum, zip(put1, put2, put3)))

plt.plot(market_range, put1)
plt.plot(market_range, put2)
plt.plot(market_range, put3)
plt.plot(market_range, riskprofile)
plt.show()
```

However, when doing this I loop back over the inputs for put1 (I'm assuming its doing this for each value in market_range?)

I would like for the strike, premium, and position inputs to be 'sticky' so that they only have to be entered once.

As always, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Take the `input`s out of the list comprehension and make variables to store the values:

```
strike = int(input("Put1 strike: "))
premium = int(input("Put1 premium: "))
position = int(input("Put1 position: "))
put1 = [put(i, strike, premium, position) for i in market_range]
```

Put this in another loop to avoid repeating the code over the 3 puts:

```
puts = []
for put_number in range(1, 4):
    strike = int(input(f"Put{put_number} strike: "))
    premium = int(input(f"Put{put_number} premium: "))
    position = int(input(f"Put{put_number} position: "))
    puts.append([put(i, strike, premium, position) for i in market_range])
risk_profile = list(map(sum, zip(*puts)))
for put in puts:
    plt.plot(market_range, put)
plt.plot(market_range, risk_profile)
plt.show()
```